# How can we see God in Kaliyuga?

Tags: gods, kali-yuga

Is one able to see God after transformation from a family man to a yogi in Kaliyuga. Also I want to know how we can get a boon from God in this Kaliyuga like that in other yugas. Is it possible?

Comment: "Is one able to see God after transformation from a family man to a yogi in Kaliyuga." No. "Also I want to know how we can get a boon from God in this Kaliyuga like that in other yugas.Is it possible?" No proof of a boon ever given to people has been shown therefore one can be reluctant.

Answer (score 3):

You will get everything you want by meditation on name of god 'Parbrahm'. 
Whoever recites his name, the riddhis and siddhis (powers) chase that person.

Just by chanting name of god will help you a lot. Try during 'brahm muharat' (4 or 5 am)  daily, atleast 15-20 minutes for a start. Pick any name of god you like but don't imagine an image in your mind. Just focus on mantra by hearing it .

Some may disagree with my answer and thats ok . :)

Comment: Why not imagining him. I do see in my mind he resting on Sheshnag, not in my dreams but when I think about him.

Comment: “ Whoever recites his name, the riddhis and siddhis (powers) chase that person.” I think so too